# Pandas DataFrame: Groupby Column, Sort By DateTime, and Truncate Group by Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks similar to:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['a', '2018-09-30 00:03:00', 'that is a glove'],
                   ['b', '2018-09-30 00:04:00', 'this is a glove'],
                   ['b', '2018-09-30 00:09:00', 'she has ball'],
                   ['a', '2018-09-30 00:05:00', 'they have a ball'],
                   ['a', '2018-09-30 00:01:00', 'she has a shoe'],
                   ['c', '2018-09-30 00:04:00', 'I have a baseball'],
                   ['a', '2018-09-30 00:02:00', 'this is a hat'],
                   ['a', '2018-09-30 00:06:00', 'he has no helmet'],
                   ['b', '2018-09-30 00:11:00', 'he has no shoe'],
                   ['c', '2018-09-30 00:02:00', 'we have a hat'],
                   ['a', '2018-09-30 00:04:00', 'we have a baseball'],
                   ['c', '2018-09-30 00:06:00', 'they have no glove'],
                   ], 
                  columns=['id', 'time', 'equipment'])


   id                 time           equipment
0   a  2018-09-30 00:03:00     that is a glove
1   b  2018-09-30 00:04:00     this is a glove
2   b  2018-09-30 00:09:00        she has ball
3   a  2018-09-30 00:05:00    they have a ball
4   a  2018-09-30 00:01:00      she has a shoe
5   c  2018-09-30 00:04:00   I have a baseball
6   a  2018-09-30 00:02:00       this is a hat
7   a  2018-09-30 00:06:00    he has no helmet
8   b  2018-09-30 00:11:00      he has no shoe
9   c  2018-09-30 00:02:00       we have a hat
10  a  2018-09-30 00:04:00  we have a baseball
11  c  2018-09-30 00:06:00  they have no glove
```

What I'd like to do is `groupby` the `id` and, within each group, sort by the `time` and then return every row up to and including the row that has the word "ball". So far, I can group and sort:

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['time'], ascending=True)).reset_index(drop=True)


   id                 time           equipment
0   a  2018-09-30 00:01:00      she has a shoe
1   a  2018-09-30 00:02:00       this is a hat
2   a  2018-09-30 00:03:00     that is a glove
3   a  2018-09-30 00:04:00  we have a baseball
4   a  2018-09-30 00:05:00    they have a ball
5   a  2018-09-30 00:06:00    he has no helmet
6   b  2018-09-30 00:04:00     this is a glove
7   b  2018-09-30 00:09:00        she has ball
8   b  2018-09-30 00:11:00      he has no shoe
9   c  2018-09-30 00:02:00       we have a hat
10  c  2018-09-30 00:04:00   I have a baseball
11  c  2018-09-30 00:06:00  they have no glove
```

However, I want the output to look like:

```
   id                 time           equipment
0   a  2018-09-30 00:01:00      she has a shoe
1   a  2018-09-30 00:02:00       this is a hat
2   a  2018-09-30 00:03:00     that is a glove
3   a  2018-09-30 00:04:00  we have a baseball
4   a  2018-09-30 00:05:00    they have a ball
6   b  2018-09-30 00:04:00     this is a glove
7   b  2018-09-30 00:09:00        she has ball
```

Notice that the group `c` has no rows being returned since it has no rows with the word "ball". Group `c` has the word "baseball" but that is not the match that we are looking for. Similarly, notice that group `a` doesn't stop at the "baseball" row since we are stopping at the row with "ball". What is the most efficient way to accomplish this both from a speed perspective as well as a memory perspective?

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with what you have done:

```
new_df = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['time'], ascending=True)).reset_index(drop=True)

new_df["mask"] = new_df.groupby("id").apply(lambda x: x["equipment"].str.contains(r"\bball\b",regex=True)).reset_index(drop=True)

result = (new_df.groupby("id").apply(lambda x : x.iloc[:x.reset_index(drop=True)["mask"].
                                     idxmax()+1 if x["equipment"].str.contains(r"\bball\b",regex=True).any() else 0])
          .reset_index(drop=True).drop("mask",axis=1))

print (result)

#
  id                 time           equipment
0  a  2018-09-30 00:01:00      she has a shoe
1  a  2018-09-30 00:02:00       this is a hat
2  a  2018-09-30 00:03:00     that is a glove
3  a  2018-09-30 00:04:00  we have a baseball
4  a  2018-09-30 00:05:00    they have a ball
5  b  2018-09-30 00:04:00     this is a glove
6  b  2018-09-30 00:09:00        she has ball
7  d  2018-09-30 00:06:00       I have a ball
```

Comment: This fails when I add an extra row to my dataframe such as `['d', '2018-09-30 00:06:00', 'I have a ball']`

Comment: Fail how? Looks fine to me even I added your new row.

Comment: You're right. Is there a way to control this to return up to only the first instance of "ball"? So, if there were multiple rows with "ball" then it stops at the first instance within each group?

Comment: Thank you. I will play with all of the responses to see which is more "obvious" before choosing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

```
# as the final expected output is sorted by id and time
# we start by doing so to the whole data
df = df.sort_values(['id','time'])

# mark the rows containing the word `ball`
has_ball = (df.equipment.str.contains(r'\bball\b') )

# cumulative number of rows with `ball` in the group
s = has_ball.groupby(df['id']).cumsum()

# there must be row with `ball`
valid_groups = has_ball.groupby(df['id']).transform('max')

print(df[valid_groups &
         (s.eq(0) |              # not containing `ball` before the first
         (s.eq(1) & has_ball)    # first row containing `ball`
         )
        ]  
     )
```

Output:

```
   id                time           equipment
4   a 2018-09-30 00:01:00      she has a shoe
6   a 2018-09-30 00:02:00       this is a hat
0   a 2018-09-30 00:03:00     that is a glove
10  a 2018-09-30 00:04:00  we have a baseball
3   a 2018-09-30 00:05:00    they have a ball
1   b 2018-09-30 00:04:00     this is a glove
2   b 2018-09-30 00:09:00        she has ball
```

Comment: Can you explain what is happening in `s = has_ball.groupby(df['id']).cumsum()`? I've only seen `groupby` for columns within the same dataframe. In this case, it looks like you are performing a groupby on `has_ball` but using a `Series` from `df`. I don't understand what is going on. It would be great if you could explain and point to the relevant documentation that describes what is happening.

Comment: you can pass the series with the same index to groupby as well. you can even do `series1.groupby([series2, series3])`. You can read further in [document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).